# WebView full problem display load html - swift

Tags: swift

With Webview, I'm showing the html code I've taken from the database. But I can't display the full html. After half of the page is not displayed, I am having this problem on all pages. Is there a limit to the string value I assign?

```
final class SSSWebView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webVİew: WKWebView!
    var formHTML = String()

    @IBAction func menuSlider(_ sender: Any) {
          toggleSideMenuView()
      }
      let keychain = KeychainSwift()

    @IBOutlet weak var logButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBAction func logoutButton(_ sender: Any) {

          let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
          let vc : MyNavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginNavControl") as! MyNavigationController
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
      }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          let loginKeychain = keychain.get("LoginSuccess")     
HTMLKodOku()
    }

    func HTMLKodOku() {
               let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
                                     client.connect("...", username: "...", password: "...", database: "...") { success in
                                     client.execute("SELECT sayfa_icerik FROM ... WHERE ... = 22", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                                             for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                                                 for row in table {
                                                    for (_, value) in row {
                                                         if let intVal = value as? String {
                                                   self.formHTML.append(String(intVal))
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }
                                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.webVİew.loadHTMLString(self.formHTML, baseURL: nil)
                                       }
                                             client.disconnect()
                                         })
                                     } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the official Apple documentation:
String is bridged to Objective-C as NSString, and a String that originated in Objective-C may store its characters in an NSString. Since any arbitrary subclass of NSString can become a String, there are no guarantees about representation or efficiency in this case.

What is the maximum length of an NSString object?

The max limit for NSString would be NSUIntegerMax characters. NSUIntegerMax is 2^32 - 1 and NSString can hold a little over 4.2 billion characters.